# Maven Goals not running on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I tried running maven goals from command line and its getting executed successfully.But when I try to execute the same using 'maven 2 tools' in eclipse, it throws,

[image: SCREENSHOT OF THE ERROR]

But, My maven is installed correctly on the system. I m not exactly sure what PATH refers to here. I guess its something thats present in eclipse preferences.

As per few stackover flow posts I modified the embedded maven version to my machine based maven version, added that path, updated the project configuration and refreshed it. But still no luck.

I m clueless as how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Do the maven configurations using Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Maven, like this

[image]

Also check the user settings, if it has correct settings.xml

Comment: This is something which I did to modify the embedded maven version. But still it didnt work

Comment: I use the plugin - m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP

Comment: Can you tell me what needs to be done in settings.xml ?

Comment: Nothing much, as in my case as I have a different repository location i have this <localRepository>C:\maven_repo\repository</localRepository>. If you have all default it should be fine.